# What could I use to gather informations about time of a reservation in JavaFx?

Tags: java, javafx

I am a student in University and our teacher gave us a project to make in teams, and he assigned my team to make an application which allows to make reservation for tennis courts at a certain day from an hour to another one (i.e. reserve a court on the 04/26/2020; the match starts at 5:30pm and ends at 7:30).
I am developing Controllers and relative FXML files. Now, I have a problem which might look stupid to the majority of you I guess: I am trying to find a way to have all the information I need from the user using a GUI and I don't know ho to make the user pick the time the match will start and finish. I tried to code it but i got stuck here:

```java
package circolotennis.controller;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker;

public class ControllerPrenotazioneDataOra extends AbstractAddPrenotazione {

    @FXML
    private Button forwardButton;

    @FXML
    private Button homeButton;

    @FXML
    private Button backButton;

    @FXML
    private DatePicker dataSceltaDatePicker;

    @FXML
    private ComboBox<?> comboOraInizio;

    @FXML
    private ComboBox<?> comboOraFine;

}
```

I am wondering what Type should i put instead of '?' ? 
And is there any method to have just certains hours of the day(like just from 5am to 12pm and for each hour only 5:00am and 5:30am)?

Sorry if my question is written quite bad but I am just learning how to code properly and if it isn't so clear you could ask, I will reply as soon as it is possible for me

Thanks

Comment: You probably want to use ComboBox<[LocalTime](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalTime.html)>.

Comment: Yes, thank you... You really helped me out